# Search all columns in an excel column and check value against file name in folder to see if exists?

Tags: vba, excel, search, directory

I have a folder with .txt files:

```
\\uksh000-file06\SharedAreas\1.0 Hewden Public\NS\Approval
```

Each text file has a random name like so:

```
NS123SHS.txt
NSg234eH.txt
NSds3461.txt
```

Most of the files file names (minus the extenstion .txt) are in my excel sheet in column c.

```
NS123SHS
NSds3461
```

I am trying to scan column c to check if the filename is found in my folder directory and if yes show a message saying found, else show a message saying not found.

So far all I've been able to figure out is how to scan my column for  specific value, which i define, however I want to be able to scan the entire column, and compare each value to see if it exists in my folder?

Can someone please show me how I might do this please? Thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = "NSds3461"
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Home").Range("C:C") 'searches all of column A
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
             MsgBox "found" 'value not found
        Else
            MsgBox "Reference Not Found" 'value not found
        End If
    End With

End If
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Dir` function.  It will allow you to search for files with a given name inside a folder.  If you want to go through the entire column, you need to use a `For Each` loop over a `Range` instead of `Find`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code bellow you'll have to update Worksheets(**1**) to the sheet index where you have the file names, and FOLDER_PATH with your info:

`\\uksh000-file06\SharedAreas\1.0 Hewden Public\NS\Approval`

.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Const FOLDER_PATH   As String = "C:\temp\"
    Const FILE_NAME_COL As Long = 3

    Dim fileNames As Variant, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim fName As String, result As String

    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    fileNames = ws.UsedRange.Columns(FILE_NAME_COL)

    For i = 2 To UBound(fileNames)

        fName = Trim(fileNames(i, 1))

        If Len(Dir(FOLDER_PATH & fName)) > 0 Then
            fName = fName & vbTab & ": Found" & vbCrLf
        Else
            fName = fName & vbTab & ": Not Found" & vbCrLf
        End If

        result = result & i - 1 & ". " & vbTab & fName
    Next

    MsgBox result, , "Search Result"

End Sub
```

.

Result:

[image]

Hope it helps